# How to paginate a custom WP_query() loop - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a blog page that calls posts with tag 'blog'. So i called a custom WP_query() object: `$blog = new WP_query('tag=blog');`.

The result works fine, but when i paginate the posts, the links always is shown even if doesn't exist more than 10 posts (the default limit).

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add the following code

`$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;`

then you query will be like as following

`$blog = new WP_query('tag=blog&posts_per_page=10&paged=' . $paged);`

Comment: The paginations still there. I don't know if it helps, but i'm using get_next_posts_link to paginate.

Comment: which code you are using for pagination.can you put overhere?

Comment: `<?php echo get_previous_posts_link(); ?>` and `<?php get_next_posts_link(); ?>` just it

Comment: Please once check the with following code
`// get_next_posts_link() usage with max_num_pages
echo get_next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $blog->max_num_pages );
echo get_previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' );`